# Call same controller when page refresh in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is my app.js file , I have to call HomeCtrl controller when page refresh,below is my code,I am new to angular.js , Please help me to sort out this problem

```
            .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$routeParams', function ($routeParams) {
                    this.name = "HomeCtrl";
                    this.params = $routeParams;
                    console.info("Home");
                }]);

})(window.angular);
```

Comment: Here is my full code:-

Comment: Not clear whatsoever what the problem is. Please elaborate on what currently happens when refresh and provide a bit of routing configuration

Comment: I have to call a controller'HomeCtrl' when I hit this url  -http://localhost/angularjs/home/

Comment: .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                    $routeProvider
                            .when('/home/', {
                                templateUrl: 'wp-content/themes/angular-theme/templates/home.html',
                                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                                controllerAs: 'home'
                            });
                  
                    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                }])

Comment: don't post code in comments, update the question itself so code is able to be formatted and readable. Also shows activity to question for more views

Comment: route config should already initialize this controller. Still not clear what is happening when you visit that url